# get id inactionscript/flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mxml

How to get all child ids of myCanvas1.Also for a specific mxml tag say `<mx:Move />` how to get its id from action script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application layout="absolute" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    [Bindable("__NoChangeEvent__")]
    [Embed(source="fruits.jpg")]
    private var fruitImageClass:Class;

    public function clickhandler(event:Event):void
    {
     //How to get all childs of myCanvas1
    }
]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#A9C0E7" borderStyle="solid" height="300" id="myCanvas1" width="300">
 <mx:Move id="fruitAnimation1" target="{fruitImage}" xTo="100" yTo="10" />
<mx:Move id="fruitAnimation2" target="{fruitImage2}" xTo="100" yTo="10" />
</mx:Canvas>


<mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#A9C0E7" borderStyle="solid" height="800" id="myCanvas" width="800">
    <mx:Image height="50" id="fruitImage" source="{fruitImageClass}" width="50" x="250" y="10" />
    <mx:Image height="50" id="fruitImage2" source="{fruitImageClass}" width="50" x="250" y="10" />


</mx:Canvas>
<mx:Button click="clickhandler(event)" label="Generate" x="100" y="316" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is children of `myCanvas1` are not visual components and this declaration has no sense. You shouldn't put your animations, effects and transitions into visual container. That's all what I can say about your question :)

Comment: Just refer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5777411/680503 where you can see where you should put `Move` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any of the getChild.. methods?
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/HierarchicalCollectionView.html#getChildren%28%29

Does this help?